# Failed to load resources node js application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to load my custom js file into my application but it's not working. I use node app engine to set the html through 'ejs' and the `index.html` renders perfectly. It's just the js file that doesn't get recognized.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Below is my project structure, html code, and the errors i'm getting.

[image: Project structure and some html code]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The errors actually take about a minute to show up after I run the application and load '/'

Comment: Can we see your app.js script? You likely need to set up a public share. /js/functions.js can not be accessed as of yet.

Comment: Just added it for you @wrxsti. And i put back the functions.js into public/ as express needs it

Comment: Well it wasn't what I thought, but @neilsimp1 is definitely correct that the functions.js needs to be in your /public/js folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions.js file shouldn't be in the `views` folder. Move that into `public/js/`. That is where express will look for that static files to serve.

The `views` folder is really only for ejs files, in your case.

Comment: Yes, I actually initially had it that way and it wasn't working. Same errors